# Google OAuth - Keeping the Client ID Secret

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, webclient, google-cloud-endpoints, clientid

**When using OAuth in the Google Cloud Endpoints JavaScript client, how do you preserve the secrecy of the client ID?**

How to implement 0Auth in the Google Cloud Endpoints JavaScript client is detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js). In the code snippet below the client ID is passed as a parameter to the OAuth method.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES,
    immediate: mode}, callback);
```

Since the end user will receive the script file in clear text, regardless of the use of HTTPS, how would you avoid handing the client ID over to every user you serve? After all, it would be rather simple to comb the JavaScript code to find the client ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. Anyone can see and intercept it (as you stated), which is the root of the confused deputy problem.

That's why you [validate your tokens](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken). For a simple explanation of token validation and the confused deputy problem, check out this great SO question and answer on [How and why is Google OAuth token validation performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241771/how-and-why-is-google-oauth-token-validation-performed).

Comment: Okay, but once the user has successfully signed in, can't an application from another tab use the browser session's credentials to make a call to the API of their own, now that they have the client ID?